# Overriding addAction in CartController

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, controllers, addtocart

I am trying to overwrite the addAction in CartController, but can not get it to work. This is my custom extension:

**app\etc\modules\Vendor_Namespace.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Vendor_Namespace>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Vendor_Namespace>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**app\etc\code\local\Vendor\Namespace\etc\config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Vendor_Namespace>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Vendor_Namespace>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <checkout>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Vendor_Namespace before="Mage_Checkout">Vendor_Namespace_CartController</Vendor_Namespace>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </checkout>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

**app\etc\code\local\Vendor\Namespace\controllers\CartController.php**

```
<?php
require_once 'Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php';
class Vendor_Namespace_CartController extends Mage_Checkout_CartController
{
    public function addAction()
    {
        $value = Mage::helper('checkout/url')->getCheckoutUrl();
        $message = $this->__('%s was added to your <a href="%s">shopping cart</a>.', Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($product->getName()), $value);
        $this->_getSession()->addSuccess($message);
        parent::addAction();
    }
    public function updateItemOptionsAction()
    {
        $value = Mage::helper('checkout/url')->getCheckoutUrl();
        $message = $this->__('%s was updated in your <a href="%s">shopping cart</a>.', Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($item->getProduct()->getName()), $value);
        $this->_getSession()->addSuccess($message);
        parent::updateItemOptionsAction();
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Why isn't this working?

Comment: check if any other module is not overriding your `CartController.php`

Comment: @Piyush I did find an extension that overwrites CartController.php but after removing that extension, it is still not working

Comment: try the solutions from the below answers

Answer (score 0):

In your **config.xml** under `frontend` tag change your code like this

```
<routers>
   <checkout>
       <args>
         <modules>
            <namespace before="Mage_Checkout">Vendor_Namespace</namespace>
         </modules>
       </args>
   </checkout>
</routers>
```

Comment: Tried this, no change.

Answer (score 0):

try this code in **config.xml**

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <checkout>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Vendor_Namespace before="Mage_Checkout">Vendor_Namespace</Vendor_Namespace>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </checkout>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```

Comment: Tried this, but I am getting this error if I do so: Controller file was loaded but class does not exist